# Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0-rc01.aar React-Native

Tags: react-native, annotations

My project on React Native. After 24 August i have this problem.
How fix it?

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0-rc01.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0-rc01) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\twent\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0-rc01\21f058f7e73e25cb36ea7093686ec9334f5b588e\annotation-experimental-1.3.0-rc01.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\twent\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0-rc01\21f058f7e73e25cb36ea7093686ec9334f5b588e\annotation-experimental-1.3.0-rc01.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

What i try to do:

1. Disable jetifier (jetifier = false);
2. Next - add in build.gradle:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
        exclude 'androidsupportmultidexversion.txt'
      }  

packagingOptions{
     pickFirst "androidsupportmultidexversion.txt"
  }
```

3. minSdkVersion 21 in build.gradle (android)
4. add classpath("com.android.tools:r8:1.6.84") in build.gradle (android)
5. Add gradle.properties
   android.minifyEnabled=false
   adnroid.shrinkResources=false
6. But this not help, and have many errors ;)

Comment: Did u get the solution?

Answer (score 7):

1. **Change distribution url in graddle wrapper**

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip

2. **update build tools in build.gradle under dependencies{}**

> classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3")

3. **add and change this under buildscript{} ext{}**

> ```
> minSdkVersion = 21
> compileSdkVersion = 31
> targetSdkVersion = 31
> androidXCore = "1.5.0"
> ```

Comment: This worked for me, I wonder what was the issue and how did you come up with the solution

Comment: just got some of the reference and error, and combine them

Comment: one big issue google and flutter and their developers don't think about backward compatibility

Comment: someone had luck with 33 compile ?

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to upgrade your SDK as [@Jonathan Suhangita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11225180/jonathan-suhangita) suggested. You can override the version to a stable one by inserting this in your app-level `build.gradle`:

```groovy
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add
`implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0-rc01"` in app/build.gradle under dependencies{}